# apache servicemix cannot load jdbc driver for apache dbcp

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am having a `servicemix bundle` which tries to `load jdbc driver` and fails with message

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

Here is my `pom.xml` file

```
      <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>
                        com.mysql.jdbc,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>
                        *
                    </DynamicImport-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuraiton>
        </plugin>
```

I have below lines mentioned in my features.xml file which is added to karaf using `features:addurl` command.

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.32</bundle>
<bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
<bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6</bundle>
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245102/maven-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver?

Comment: Is there a route that is defined, if so please post it? Is the mysql-connector installed?

Comment: @user7294900: mvn clean install works perfectly fine. The issue I am facing is something to do with osgi import - export

Comment: @J_D: There are many entries in `route print`. Should I look for any specific entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the `servicemix wrapper jar for dbcp` @https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.4_3

Resulting pom entry

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4_3</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Note: while using karaf or any OSGi always give attention to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of bundle/jar file to see what it imports(`Import-Package`)  and what it exports(`Export-Package`)**

As the below `karaf-console` screenshot of dbcp bundle, `com.mysql.jdbc` pakage is imported for servicemix dbcp

[image]

The same import as in screenshot should have apeared for `<bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4$Import-Package=com.mysql.jdbc</bundle>`  but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found while using service mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400642/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-found-while-using-service-mix)? The user added the below to the Pom:

```
<osgi-import-package>
  org.apache.commons.dbcp
</osgi-import-package>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.4_3</version>
</dependency>
```

And also changed the route from

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
```

to

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

Comment: `servicemix.bundles` for `dbcp` is nothing but `bundle wrap` which I am already achieving by `<bundle>wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.32</bundle>
 <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
 <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6</bundle>` and also I am already using dbcp as data source in my code so don't need to change that. I have update my question.